# PDF is getting change after loading using PDFBOX jar

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a PDF having first page as different page ( as we have in MS word functionality under "Design" tab ). and the same PDF is passed to PDFBOX using below code :

```
File originalPdfFile = new File("D:\\AsposeOutput_temp.pdf");
PDDocument originalDocument = PDDocument.load(originalPdfFile);
originalDocument.save("D:\\pdfBoxGen.pdf");
```

But when i am opening the PDF that is generated by PDFBOX, is modified. I have attached the input PDF (named AsposeOutput_temp.pdf) and output PDF (named : pdfBoxGen.pdf). I want the PDF to same as i am passing as input.

File links : https://gofile.io/?c=lLPpQz

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What version of PDFBox are you using?

Comment: I just tested your code using the current PDFBox develop (3.0.0-SNAPSHOT), the latest 2.0.x (2.0.17), and the latest 1.8.x (1.8.16). With none of these versions I could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @hagarwal i am using PDFBOX 2.0.17 version.

Comment: @pks even I am also not able to reproduce the issue. I am using using the latest version 2.0.17. The pdf is getting generating correctly.

Comment: @hagarwal could it be you have several different .jar versions in your classpath?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have only one jar in my classpath. The pdf is getting correctly generated using above code & latest pdfbox dependency.

Comment: pks - As neither @hagarwal nor I could reproduce the issue, you should look for a cause specific to your setup. E.g. multiple, different PDFBox versions on your classpath as proposed by @Tilman; or your code being executed with a different `AsposeOutput_temp.pdf` file in `D:` than you expected; probably Aspose was still in the process of saving when you loaded the PDF; maybe you have no permissions to overwrite `D:\pdfBoxGen.pdf` and you see an old file there all the time.

Comment: After looking at the files (in the "bad" file there are similarities between page 1 and 3) I suspect that the workflow shown in the question is not what actually happens. I.e. I doubt that the OP can reproduce the problem just by running the code shown without anything else. I rather suspect that there was some complex workflow, and that code was reduced but never tested alone.

Comment: Thank you  guys for your quick comments. I got the issue. The issue was with the input file that i am generating using Aspose library.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got this sorted out. Please delete your question, or answer it yourself if you think that the cause you mentioned should be shared with future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above problem. There was no issue with PDFBOX library. it was with the Aspose word.The input file that was passed to PDFBOX library , was having section break internally and the same was making the improper alignment of footer.